the sum of $O_p$ --$ O_p(s^2\frac{\log d}{n}+s\sqrt{\frac{\log d}{n}}) $
I read papers in the area of inference for high-dimensional graphical models and these papers always state the convergence rate of the estimator. Using $O_p$ is a good choice.
Maybe I made some mistakes and I have some questions about the sum of $O_p$. I know that people often use the property $O_p(a_n)+O_p(b_n)=O_p(a_n+b_n)$. it’s slightly different.
For example, here, the proof of theorem B.4 in page 25 says that
$$
O_p(\sqrt{\frac{\log d}{n}})+O_p(s^2(\log d/n)^{3/2}+s\frac{\log d}{n})+O_p(s^2 \frac{\log d}{n}+s\sqrt{\frac{\log d}{n}})=O_p(s^2(\log d/n)^{3/2}+s^2 \frac{\log d}{n}+s\sqrt{\frac{\log d}{n}})
$$
where $s$ constrains the maximum degree of the graph and $d$ is the number of the features. This article has many similar situations, and I don't know why these equations are correct. When the authors try to bound term (iii).b (page26), they get
$$
O_p(s^2\frac{\log d}{n}+s\sqrt{\frac{\log d}{n}}).
$$
the second term is the square root of the first term. Why can they appear at the same time? I mean, Why can't one of them control the other?
My question

why can we omit some terms in $O_p$?

$\frac{\log d}{n}$ stays constant or goes to infinity when discussing high-dimensional statistics.

$s$ represents the "true sparsity" parameter and stays constant or goes to infinity in the above situation. Does s depend on n?



In general, $s,d,n \to \infty$, but the rates at which they tend to infinity may depend on the situation. By keeping track of all three variables in the $O$ notation, you can analyze different situations (e.g., $s=cd$ or $s = c\log d$) separately.
In the original expression, replacing $(1+s) \sqrt{ \log d / n}$ with $s \sqrt{\log d / n}$ is fine since $1+s \le 2s$ for sufficiently large $s$. Replacing $(s+s^2) \log d / n$ with $s^2 \log d / n$ can be justified similarly.
I am not sure of the reason for keeping both $s^2 \log d / n$ and $s \sqrt{\log d / n}$. If both terms are vanishing, the latter term will dominate. Maybe I'm missing something though.

the proof of THM b4 also has a similar situation, $s^2\log d/n$ and $s^2(\log d/n)^{3/2}$. I don't know why the authors keep the two items related to $s^2$
